# heat and fan pacing after ubuntu 12.10 is installed alongside windows 7

Tags: overheating, fan

i tried touch `/etc/fancontrol` it is helpless

i tried the following but to no avail;
install mesa-utils and mesa-utils-extras and reboot
if the problem remains let us know

```
$ sudo apt-get install mesa-utils mesa-utils-extra
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through same problem sometime back. Tried lot many things but didn't get grip over the problem. You can try whatever solutions given around over the internet.

But I suggest you to re-install ubuntu. But remember to use the correct usb tool to install. I mean correct software to make bootable usb. I recommend "unetbootin".

This is actually a problem which comes due to incorrect linux installation.

Comment: i did used unetbootin ,,,may be i will try once again reinstalling as you suggest.

Comment: @jampel I can't guarantee this but I gave hell of a try to what you're facing right now. So that was the final thing that worked out for me. So I'm suggesting you this. Try downloading a fresh image too (of ubuntu 12.10). Sometimes silly things do workout.